# nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting error when i am  clicking on post method in postman and getting blank response and error is
Employee not founddetached entity passed to persist: com.example.restapiexample.models.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.restapiexample.models.Employee
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_0_0_, employee0_.employee_age as employee2_0_0_, employee0_.employee_name as employee3_0_0_, employee0_.employee_salary as employee4_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from employee where id=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.employee_age as employee2_0_, employee0_.employee_name as employee3_0_, employee0_.employee_salary as employee4_0_ from employee employee0_

```js
@Entity


@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    
      // ------------------------
      // PRIVATE FIELDS
      // ------------------------
      
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private int id;
      
      @NotNull
      private String employee_name;
      
      @NotNull
      private int employee_salary;
      
      @NotNull
      private int employee_age;
      
      public Employee() { }
      
      public Employee(int id) { 
        this.id = id;
      }

      public Employee(String employee_name, int employee_salary, int employee_age) {
        this.employee_name = employee_name;
        this.employee_salary = employee_salary;
        this.employee_age = employee_age;
      }
      public String getName() {
          return employee_name;
      }
      public int getSalary() {
          return employee_salary;
      }
      public int getAge() {
          return employee_age;
      }
      public void setAge(int age) {
          this.employee_age = age;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
          this.employee_name = name;
      }
      public void setSalary(int salary) {
          this.employee_salary = salary;
      }
      public void setId(int value) {
        this.id = value;
      }
      public int getId() {
        return id;
      }
    
}
```

```css
package com.example.restapiexample.controllers;



import com.example.restapiexample.models.Employee;
import com.example.restapiexample.models.EmployeeDao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    
    @RequestMapping("/getall")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Employee> getAll() {
        return employeeDao.getAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        Employee emp = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Responded", "EmployeeController");
        
        try {
            emp = employeeDao.getById(id);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("Employee not found" + ex.getMessage());
             return ResponseEntity.accepted().headers(headers).body(emp);
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(emp);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> create(@RequestBody Employee postdata) {
        Employee emp = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Responded", "EmployeeController");
        
        try {
            emp = employeeDao.create(postdata);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("Employee not found" + ex.getMessage());
             return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(emp);
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(emp);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Responded", "EmployeeController");
        
        try {
            Employee emp = new Employee(id);
            isDeleted = employeeDao.delete(emp);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("Employee not found to delete" + ex.getMessage());
             return "Error deleting the Employee: " + ex.toString();
        }
        
        if(isDeleted) {
            return "Employee succesfully deleted!";
        }
        return "Error! Employee deleted!";
    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.restapiexample.models;


import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class EmployeeDao {
    @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;
      /**
       * Return all the employee stored in the database.
       */
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<Employee> getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Employee").getResultList();
      }
      
      public Employee getById(int id) {
          return entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
      }
      
      /**
       * Save the employee in the database.
       */
      public Employee create(Employee emp) {
        entityManager.persist(emp);
        int id = emp.getId();
        return entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
      }
      /**
       * delete the employee in the database.
       */
      public Boolean delete(Employee emp) {
          if (entityManager.contains(emp))
              entityManager.remove(emp);
          else
              entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(emp));
          
          return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: This is just too much code to read for a random user. Please read [this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/), then come back and reduce the code into a small but meaningful size that exposes the problem more clearly. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26589257).

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
emp = entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
then entityManager.delete(emp);
```

Comment: where to add this?emp = entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
then entityManager.delete(emp);

Comment: instead of creating a new Employee on delete, instead of this: try {
            Employee emp = new Employee(id);
            isDeleted = employeeDao.delete(emp);

Comment: i have tried this but still i am getting error after clicking on Post method in postman tool and its not creating employee and getting error is--> Employee not founddetached entity passed to persist: com.example.restapiexample.models.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.restapiexample.models.Employee

Comment: there are too many errors in your code. Annotations at the wrong places and so on. Take a look at this for a reference. https://github.com/aballaci/springboot-jpa-sakila/tree/master/src/main then keep just your Employee model and try again...